# Is there anyway to stop a download on Steam?

Tags: steam

Steam recently started downloading an update for *Super Monday Night Combat*. Remembering the fact that the game never ran properly for me, and that I was unable to ever find any fix, I impatiently paused the download and deleted all local files from my computer.

The problem is, Steam is still trying to download the update. I've already restarted Steam. Even tried to uninstall the game completely, but it's still trying to download this update! I'd rather avoid having to hunt down the specific files and remove them manually.

**Is there any way I can force this download to stop?**

Comment: Did you try uninstalling/removing it within Steam?

Comment: @MatthewRead I did. It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: OK what happened there?  Obviously it failed, but was there an error message or anything?

Comment: No error message or anything. The download just continues trying to download unless I have it paused.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your library list, right click on the game you wish to cancel the download for and click 'Uninstall' from the 'Manage' menu.

[image: Image showing the right click menu from the Steam library]

After a confirmation prompt, this will remove the data that has already been downloaded and remove the game from the download list.

[image: Image showing the Steam application uninstall confirmation]

Comment: I guess my computer was just acting up. I had to do this twice, but it finally worked.

Comment: Strange, would be nice to know if this is reproducible - hadn't even noticed you mentioned this in your originally question, saw the title and answered it so sorry for the duplication. :) I haven't ever come across this not working but I known Steam can be awfully temperamental at times.

Comment: I had the same problem with CoD:MW3. Only after 3 or 4 tries it stopped downloading it again.

Comment: I've done this at least three times for a certain game and it's remaining in my downloads tab.

Comment: I don't even see the option to  delete local content at all when I right click a game.  Is this feature.  Included in the full screen mode?

Comment: I'm thinking this no longer exists, the answer was from 10+years ago!  trying the solutions Milk and Drake left

Comment: @BillK thanks for the notification, I have updated my answer for the current version of the Steam client

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for every game on Steam:

Go to your library, right click on the game you're downloading and want to remove and select "Delete local content". That's all. You don't need to stop or restart Steam this way.

Answer (score 5):

1. Close Steam
2. Locate your C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\downloading folder
3. Delete everything under Downloading (not a specific folder just everything)
4. Start steam - product should download anew.

Answer (score 3):

1. Close Steam
2. Locate you `<Steam>/steamapps/downloading` subfolder
3. Try to look if it does exist a subfolder called `/440/` (TF2 app id) and delete it
4. Relaunch Steam

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here is an answer for a new decade.  The other answers here don't quite work any more (Even the accepted one, downvoted it sadly to make it less prominant).

This problem has been driving me nuts.  I finally figured it out.

delete the files in steamapps/downloading (I just deleted everything in the directory)

Delete the directory named after the game in steamapps/common

Then the real trick:  In steamapps there should be an appmanifest for each game.  Go through them and look for one that contains the name of the app you are after and delete it.

If it's difficult to find the right appmanifest to delete, you can use "open with" and select notepad, and select "always use this app to open this type of file" checkbox.  After opening one this way you can select all the the rest of the files at the same time and right-click/open to open them all at once, then just close the notepads until you find the one you are after, the filename you want to delete will be in the title bar.