# How to stop downloading a game in Steam?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anyway to stop a download on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74367/is-there-anyway-to-stop-a-download-on-steam)

I started to download Team Fortress 2 but later on decided not, so I went to my downloads and I couldn't find any way to delete the download, all I could was stop it from completing. And it had barely started to download as well so I don't want to wait for it to finish and then uninstall it.