# How can I remove older items from the downloads page, and display newer ones?

Tags: steam

The downloads section of Steam's has been frustrating me. It's clogged up by some items I haven't been touching in months, whereas fresh downloads don't show up in the list. To add to the frustration, the status bar only shows the progress of the fresh downloads, ignoring the staler ones.

Removing local content of games in the downloads page does *not* remove them from my downloads page for some reason.

How can I make the downloads page stop showing these few old downloads, and show newer ones instead?

Comment: Far too many questions in one post, it's not very clear what is your actual question to give an answer to, then.

Comment: nice games!! :D

Comment: @Gnoupi I broke it up into separate 'questions' because someone answering a general/vague question might not provide information about each page, or all of the features, etc.  I was just outlining what information I wanted, so nothing was missed.

Comment: I'd really like to make a meta thread because I *really think* this shouldn't have been closed, but I'll probably just make a hash of it.

Comment: Did you restart steam after deleting local content?

Comment: @Fluttershy Yes.  One of them is no longer listed in my downloads, but it's also no longer in my library.  =[

Comment: Was it a free-to-play game?

Comment: @Fluttershy Yes.  And I've just learned that removing the local files only removes free to play games from your library.  Godammit, what a waste of time.  It appears to be working for everything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to stop a download on Steam?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74367/is-there-anyway-to-stop-a-download-on-steam)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't help you with how to fix the problem, but...

(**Q4**) Yes, yours seems to be broken. The downloads page *should* display the items which

- are currently being downloaded,
- would be being downloaded, but are paused (either by your action or because you're playing a game), or
- have completed downloading (these have a button to dismiss them, and also go away when you restart Steam).

(**Q1**) In all cases the status display at the bottom should display counts of the above 3 types of items, and a progress bar for downloads in progress. If you have a game that needs an update, then when you launch Steam it *should* start updating *and* appear in the Downloads list and summary.

(**Q3**) You can't cancel updates to installed games. If things are working right, you have the choice between letting the download/update finish, or doing a “Delete Local Content” (i.e. uninstall), which should cancel the download as well as deleting files. That this didn't work for you is another symptom of the problem.

(**Q2**) This is not normal behavior. No game should behave like this. Most likely you have some corruption in your Steam configuration which is specific to those games. For what it's worth, the usual general troubleshooting advice I've heard is “delete `ClientRegistry.blob`”. I get the impression this will not delete any of your settings, but I don't actually know and haven't ever done it myself.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but Steam does start automatically updating my stuff when I open it... some of the time.  It doesn't start all of the dozens of paused ones I have, though.  Also, deleting local content isn't ideal, because it removes the game from my library.  Gah.

Comment: @GnomeSlice They should stay in your library list but be dimmed, unless (a) they are free games, which you can reinstall from the store page, or (b) you are looking at the “Installed” view (popup menu next to the search box). If that's not happening, then congratulations, you have more problem.

Answer (score 3):

The particular thing which seems to be your problem (aside from the disappearing game), is that recently, Steam changed the format of their delivered content. As such, games which have an update need to be "converted", prior to actually launch the update.

This causes the "download paused" in the game list, while they don't show up in the download view. To get rid of it, you have to actually launch the game. Steam will propose to convert the game, and it should appear in the download view afterwards.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answers my question.  I want to get rid of the games in my downloads page that are like 8 gb and are always there for some reason.  Maybe I misread this answer, it's late, and I'll read it again tomorrow.

Comment: @GnomeSlice - you have a lot of questions in your "question". This answers the question 1, most likely, and your first screenshot.